# IE can't manage "global" variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6YjXt/) code :

```
<div class="riga" style="border-top:0;">
    <div class="col3" id="txtValoreCatastale">0,00 euro</div>            
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   txtValoreCatastale = $('#txtValoreCatastale');
</script>
```

seems I get an error :

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method
show, Row 33 Char 4
```

that will Broke (on my whole original code) some of my script! 
But if I wrote :

```
var txtValoreCatastale = $('#txtValoreCatastale');
```

it works perfectly.

Why this behaviour? Another massive bug?

Comment: IE and Chrome create a global variable for each element with an ID. It seems you cannot directly override it (`window.txtValoreCatastale1 = ...`) but using `var` seems to circumvent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE creates its own global variable for every element id you use. So the problem is, IE has already created its own variable called txtValoreCatastale. By adding var in front of it you are telling IE that in the scope of your function it is a local variable and so IE allows it. If you called it some other name like someOtherVariableName it would have worked without var in front.

Comment: in fact it should print (with the alert) `0,00 euro`

Comment: It doesn't work because IE doesn't turn it into a jQuery object. It is a DOM element. So you can make it a jQuery object by doing $(txtValoreCatastale) if you wanted to. Or if you want to use it as IE created it get the HTML like this: txtValoreCatastale.innerHTML.

Comment: Right! You rock ;) Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick thought: When you specify a DIV with an id, it becomes a global variable with that name. So you already have a global variable called txtValoreCatastale, which is a DOM element. It should work fine if you either change the ID or the variable name.